# Polymer centered splitter

Tags: polymer, splitter, paper-elements

I want to center splitter horizontally or vertically.
I'm able to do it using `flex` but now splitter is locked!

https://ele.io/ggirou/wicked-greenbean

```html
<div horizontal layout>
  <div flex>left</div>
  <core-splitter direction="left"></core-splitter>
  <div flex>right</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When using a splitter, only one sibling should be `flex`. This is because `flex:1 1` will always override position and size on the element. They can both have `layout` if you would like, though. In your case, the left element should not have `flex`, but the right should.